# Issue When I set shard key

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a collection and I set shard it.
I have errors while I add a shard key!!!

```
mongos> sh.shardCollection('IBSng.connection_log', {login_time:1})
```

But I was shown this error:
Even I set compound shard with logout_time field with login_time, But the result shown to me this error.

```
{
    "proposedKey" : {
        "login_time" : 1
    },
    "curIndexes" : [
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "IBSng.connection_log"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "user_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "user_id_1",
            "ns" : "IBSng.connection_log"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "ras_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "ras_id_1",
            "ns" : "IBSng.connection_log"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "retry_count" : 1
            },
            "name" : "retry_count_1",
            "ns" : "IBSng.connection_log"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "credit_used" : 1
            },
            "name" : "credit_used_1",
            "ns" : "IBSng.connection_log"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "details.mac" : 1
            },
            "name" : "details.mac_1",
            "ns" : "IBSng.connection_log"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "username" : 1
            },
            "name" : "username_1",
            "ns" : "IBSng.connection_log"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "type_details.in_bytes" : 1,
                "type_details.out_bytes" : 1
            },
            "name" : "type_details.in_bytes_1_type_details.out_bytes_1",
            "ns" : "IBSng.connection_log"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "details.kill_reason" : 1
            },
            "name" : "details.kill_reason_1",
            "ns" : "IBSng.connection_log"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "details.terminate_cause" : 1
            },
            "name" : "details.terminate_cause_1",
            "ns" : "IBSng.connection_log"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "login_time" : -1,
                "logout_time" : -1
            },
            "name" : "login_time_-1_logout_time_-1",
            "ns" : "IBSng.connection_log",
            "sparse" : false
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "please create an index that starts with the shard key before sharding."
}
```

I Waiting for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index for `{login_time:1}`, this is different to that compound one you have done.

Comment: Thank, But can I set descending index instead of ascending index?

Comment: @user255327, of course you can. Just keep consistent.